# GSON : convert json to java object with maps as fields

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON like this:

```
String json = 
  "{\n" + 
  "\tfeeType: [{2:\"SALESCOMM_GST\"},{3:\"SALESCOMM\"}],\n" +
  "\tfeeBasis: [{0:\"AMOUNT\"},{1:\"CPS\"},{2:\"PERCENT\"}]\n" +
  "}"
```

I want to convert into an java object like this.

```
private class MyObj{
        public Map<Integer, String> feeType;
        public Map<Integer, String> feeBasis;

        public Map<Integer, String> getFeeType() {
            return feeType;
        }

        public void setFeeType(Map<Integer, String> feeType) {
            this.feeType = feeType;
        }

        public Map<Integer, String> getFeeBasis() {
            return feeBasis;
        }

        public void setFeeBasis(Map<Integer, String> feeBasis) {
            this.feeBasis = feeBasis;
        }
    }
```

I tried using gsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization but it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

**EDIT**
Got approval to implement in another way. (Using Maps instead of Lists)

new JSON:

```
String json = 
  "{\n" + 
  "\t\"feeType\": {2:\"SALESCOMM_GST\",3:\"SALESCOMM\"},\n" + 
  "\t\"feeBasis\": {0:\"AMOUNT\",1:\"CPS\",2:\"PERCENT\"}\n" + 
  "}"
```

Comment: `feeType` and `feeBasis ` are not Map but Array

Comment: @MaximShoustin Yes, My requirement is to store those as a Map.

Comment: Got approval to implement in another way. Thanks.

Comment: new JSON:  "{\n" +
                "\t\"feeType\": {2:\"SALESCOMM_GST\",3:\"SALESCOMM\"},\n" +
                "\t\"feeBasis\": {0:\"AMOUNT\",1:\"CPS\",2:\"PERCENT\"}\n" +
                "}"

Comment: So, did you manage to work it out now? It should be a straightforward conversion.

Comment: yes, I have thanks.